Automate Microsoft Security alerts on an Azure DevOps Work Item
I have a project that should make it possible to automate Microsoft Security alerts by creating a work item on Azure DevOps with the description of the alert generated by Security and the direct access link.
How can I do this?
If you have any ideas, I'd love to hear from you.
I tried to do this with a power automaton. It worked perfectly except for putting the direct access link to the alert. Impossible to put it
